# Windows 10 - diskperf.sys - INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, bsod

I am experimenting with a custom storage class filter driver (based on diskperf.sys that comes with WDK 8). When I install this custom filter driver and reboot the machine, Windows 10 displays **INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE** screen of death and won't boot.

*Safe Mode*, *Last Known Good Configuration*, *System Restore*, *Boot Logging* nothing seems to work. It just keeps showing me the Advance Boot Options menu after each try.

I tried to get rid of the installed driver from command line [using the original installation inf file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/using-an-inf-file-to-uninstall-a-file-system-filter-driver) and I believe the driver was removed but the system still won't boot. My only resort is to reinstall Windows when this happens. I've already done that twice but I need a quicker way to get my Windows running when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot your computer from a WinPE disk, then load the **SYSTEM** registry hive that could be located in **Windows\System32\Config** directory.

Next navigate to the following key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318`}. Remove only *diskperf* from the **UpperFilters** value.

Save your changes and reboot. The system should boot successfully.

Comment: you sir are a savior!

Comment: now, is there a way to install `diskperf.sys` only on my *secondary drive*? I tried using [addfilter utility](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/storage/filters/addfilter) but that shows up a yellow exclamation mark and doesn't seem to be working. Right click INF -> Install works but it installs the driver to all the drives on my sysem.

Comment: The default .INF should only install and copy diskperf.sys to your system partition, not all drives. What type of function do you want to achieve with diskperf.sys driver?

Comment: I am trying to customize the driver so I can pause OS Reads/Writes to my secondary drive when required. Since it is a class driver, right click -> install, installs the driver to all disk drives.

Comment: Each disk drive has a disk number that you can get from both Windows application and diskperf driver. In the driver's read/write routine, you can decide to deny or allow read/write request by the disk number.

Comment: That's a good idea. But is there any way to restrict installation of the driver only to a specific disk drive? Instead of having to decide based on disk id inside my filter driver code.

Comment: No such solution yet, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual machine for such experiments.
you can try https://www.virtualbox.org/ , it is free.

It will not help your restore Windows, but will help you to prevent such situation in future. Virtual machine support snapshooting, or you can simply delete/install new.

Regards, Michael

Comment: Can you explain how to resolve OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

have resolve about this issue? I meet the same error,and windbg info is
INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE (7b)
During the initialization of the I/O system, it is possible that the driver
for the boot device failed to initialize the device that the system is
attempting to boot from, or it is possible for the file system that is
supposed to read that device to either fail its initialization or to simply
not recognize the data on the boot device as a file system structure that
it recognizes.   In the former case, the argument (#1) is the address of a
Unicode string data structure that is the ARC name of the device from which
the boot was being attempted.   In the latter case, the argument (#1) is the
address of the device object that could not be mounted.
If this is the initial setup of the system, then this error can occur if
the system was installed on an unsupported disk or SCSI controller.   Note
that some controllers are supported only by drivers which are in the Windows
Driver Library (WDL) which requires the user to do a custom install.   See
the Windows Driver Library for more information.
This error can also be caused by the installation of a new SCSI adapter or
disk controller or repartitioning the disk with the system partition.   If
this is the case, on x86 systems the boot.ini file must be edited or on ARC
systems setup must be run.   See the "Advanced Server System Administrator's
User Guide" for information on changing boot.ini.
If the argument is a pointer to an ARC name string, then the format of the
first two (and in this case only) longwords will be:
USHORT Length;
USHORT MaximumLength;
PWSTR Buffer;
That is, the first longword will contain something like 00800020 where 20
is the actual length of the Unicode string, and the next longword will
contain the address of buffer.   This address will be in system space, so
the high order bit will be set.
If the argument is a pointer to a device object, then the format of the first
word will be:
USHORT Type;
That is, the first word will contain a 0003, where the Type code will ALWAYS
be 0003.
Note that this makes it immediately obvious whether the argument is a pointer
to an ARC name string or a device object, since a Unicode string can never
have an odd number of bytes, and a device object will always have a Type
code of 3.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff858d60807798, Pointer to the device object or Unicode string of ARC name
Arg2: ffffffffc0000034, (reserved)
Arg3: 0000000000000000, (reserved)
Arg4: 0000000000000001, (reserved)

Comment: Hi Chang, no one is going to read a wall of text.  Please break it up into shorter sentences and into paragraphs.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228521)

Comment: Hi Rohit ，sorry，  i build the diskperf.sys（from wdk8.0 demo），and use AddFilter.exe to disk ，PC boot is normal when choose data disk when reboot,  but PC will BSOD（INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE）when choose the system disk  and reboot，I  think my problem like Madhur‘s question ，so have any advice？thanks